# How can I address professional complaints from my partner about my direct reports?

Tags: management

My partner and I work for the same IT company, we're in different teams but she often comes to people in the team I manage when she needs help.

There are some people in my team who are dropping the ball with answers. I know this and am working on addressing it longer term. She doesn't like useless answers (one of the reasons why I love her) and quite rightly when she's given one she raises it with their manager... me.

This makes things very difficult for me, if any other member of the business reported problems with one of my team members I'd professionally point out that they're not being very supportive. However as it's my wife I think there's a danger I'd be seen as playing favorites or taking her side.

How can I ensure she (and everyone) gets the quality answers they need without losing the respect of my team for taking my wife's side?

Comment: Is your partner the only one that is complaining? If not, then I don't see a problem. You will have a list of complaints from multiple people that you can use to train the team members.

Comment: Have you gotten any push back from your team when you mention the problems she has had?

Comment: Well if they make shitty answers you can just Point that out, shouldnt matter if it was your wife or not. Worst case just spit up the Archive and tell X to explain mail Y. When he gives you a proper answer tell X why he didnt give that Response instead :)

Comment: Do other people approach your team for help?

Comment: This sounds like a question about balancing or prioritising between personal and professional commitments/responsibilities. The title suggests the OP has already made a decision of favouring personal over professional.

Comment: If no other proposed solution works, there's always divorce... :P

Answer (score 24):

When you work with a partner or spouse or child, you have be able to step back from that relationship at work. Treat her exactly as you would treat anyone else.

If she has a complaint about your team, she gets the same professional courtesy as anyone who has a complaint. That means that you defend your team when the person complaining is wrong and correct the team when the person complaining is correct.

What is critical to your relationship to the team is that you push back any unfair criticism. They will know, or should know, when the criticism is fair.

When people perceive favoritism it is usually because the unfair stuff is passed through uncritically especially when you don't do that for anyone else. It is perceived as favoritism if her stuff always takes priority too, so watch out for that.

You and your spouse need to have an agreement that you will push back things if, in your judgement, you do not think they are correct or they are not your highest priority. You are not married at work and your interests, being in different departments, are going to come into conflict at times. It is important that there be that conflict and that it be known publicly.

Comment: *You are not married at work* - in what sense is that statement true? Marriage doesn't mean agreement.

Comment: I'd emphasise that having a discussion with your wife, explaining the situation you're being placed in, and warning her in advance that if you disagree with her assessment, you're not going to defend the team the same way you would with anyone else. Assuming you're able to communicate with your wife, this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

I think there's a bunch of questions you need to answer before we can give you a more qualitative answer. For example:

**History**

Do these employees have a history of providing poor quality answers? If they do then you need to deal with them as with any poorly performing team member, and do whatever it is you do when that happens.

If however, they are typically reliable people you have to ask yourself why a mistake was made. Was it to spite you, your wife, or her team? Or maybe ...

**Unfair Situation?**

Are they dropping the ball because they're being caught unprepared? Because they're being pulled in too many directions? Is it unnusual for them to be approached by people from other departments and being asked to answer questions? Is there a more appropriate channel for these sort of requests?

What this comes down to is whether or not the question being asked of them is a standard one which they should be able to provide info on, or whether they are being put in an unfair situation.

The way you tell it, your wife walks up to them, requests information, or a solution to a problem, and then storms off to you when she finds the answer inadequate. Is this the standard operating procedure when someone has a question for your team? Or is there a more appropriate process which your wife should be following so that these people have a chance to better think out their answer?

For example, if the process is typically that a request is submitted, or an email sent, and she's just asking them in person then maybe they're answering under pressure, and with incomplete knowledge.

**Conclusion**

First and foremost you have to make sure that the proper process is enforced when information is requested of your team. Those people have to know that you have their back when people are abusing their time, or making unfair requests of them.

If that is the case, and someone is simply underperforming then enforce the rules fairly. If many people make the same mistake maybe run a training session. Send out memos remind people that information must be checked to be up to date before provided to others. If one person's screw up is really bad then maybe have a private conversation with said person advising them to up their game, etc. This is all standard managerial stuff, and should be no different from how you'd handle such a complaint from another manager or team leader.

Comment: In most corporate setting I've been in the lower end workers are shielded from being asked directly. They have to talk to the manager in charge before talking directly. Even if they "dropped the ball" the asking person would be in more trouble.

Comment: @Dan - same, that's why I'm asking the OP all these questions.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you are between the rock and a hard place my friend. Regardless what you, do, or how right your significant other is, as long as you are related, your team will look at you as, you are protecting your partner, even though they know deep inside that you are doing rightfully so. It is workplace politics and subordinates, especially disgruntled ones, will play this "relationship" card, over and again.

I know this will sound quite counter-productive but, when your partner gets into this situation, instead of coming to you directly, a coworker from the same team should come to the same person with the same question and if that person gets the same brush-off answer, then he/she comes to you and you should keep your impartiality as that person have no relation to you. On the other hand this person, who is not related to is getting a better treatment than your partner, then you might have another issue in your hands. As in, your subordinates are undermining you because of this relationship status and it is a whole new can of worms, which I am not going to open here and now, prematurely.

Comment: As Long as the op doesnt treat his wife as a VIP, his subordinates cant complain, and if they do replace their ungratefull asses

Comment: Good thinking but _replacing their ungrateful heineys_ is creating  a whole new ball game that one should have good lawyers for.

Comment: that is a Problem for my Boss not me :D

Comment: The old rule used to be treat friends and family more harshly than other workers.  It keeps complaints down in two ways, since when people see that, the worst thing that will go through their heads is "If he treats family like that, I'd better watch myself."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your team feels that there is an attitude problem. Someone from another team who is just impossible to please and runs straight to the boss, and the boss is under her thumb and does whatever she says.

Your job is to back your team. Are you doing that? Starting with their username, I think you and your wife working in the same company close together might not be beneficial to your team and to your company.

If you disagree, take action to make your team feel that you have their back.

Answer (score -1):

During the work day, treat your partner exactly as you would any other co-worker you are on good terms with. That's what the company is paying you to do.

Answer (score -2):

Don't let (any) outside people go directly to your team. It puts your team in a very awkward spot anyway. Examples: Say you have assigned Task A. Someone else comes along and gives Task B. Now your employee has to choose... Do they finish A with a slow turnaround on B, do they drop A to do B first?

Instead, all requests to your team come to you and you **manage** the work by prioritizing and assigning. Then if something (anything) is taking too long or not done satisfactorily, you go around and ask why. At that point it's not a task for some outside manager that they're not doing properly, it is a task for you.

There are lots of ways to make this work, but a good starting point for the type of IT team that gets a lot of small outside requests is to use a ticket tracker with a Kanban board.

You will probably need frequent reminders at first, insisting that outside people are not to go directly to your team and also reminding your team to not accept outside work.

Comment: Yes micromanage and remove opportunities for learning, completely.

Comment: I'm unsure why this is getting downvoted? It's solid advice. A manager should not go to another manager's workers and make requests or demands then go complain about it. It sounds very unprofessional and causes the workers to be in a bad position because they're always wrong and worry about being "told on."